# ASP.NET MVC 3 AuthorizeAttribute not working, not even being called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

<s>I was having trouble getting AuthorizeAttribute to work for an out of the box MVC 3 app. So I created my own attribute inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute and overriding all methods and adding break points to see what was going on.</s>

But the problem is, the attribute code is NEVER called! Any idea what could cause this?

It is a completely blank MVC 3 app with a HomeController with an Index method. Form authentication set to redirect to ~/Account/LogOn. But it seems it just doesn't load the [Authorize] attribute...

**EDIT:**

Sorry guys, I must really be tired today :) it is in fact not a totally blank project. I have some Ninject code that provides a repository to my HomeController. If I disable this and create a parameterless constructor on the HomeController the AuthorizeAttribute seems to work ok.

Any idea why Ninject dependency injection would interfere with the Authorize attribute?

-- 
Christian

Comment: Are you sure it is your AuthorizeAttribute over that that action/controller, maybe it's default one? Try to prefix it with namespace. If it will not work, please provide some more code for us to analyze.

Answer (score 1):

And you say you have the following settings on your `web.config`?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/logOn" />
</authentication>
```

How are you using your authorize attribute, could we see some code?

You might want to take a look at this step by step "[Authenticating Users with Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs)" guide.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom attribute and enabling Forms auth aren't enough. You still have to decorate the Controllers / Actions for which you want the filter to execute with the attribute.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // ...your code
}
```

or

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController
{
    // ... your actions
}
```

**Edit** As tpeczek said in comments, also ensure that [Authorize] is using your AuthorizeAttribute and not System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.